# data training with R where data preprocessed into PCA components?

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, knn

I would like to train a `knn` using `caret::train` to classify digits (classic problem) employing a PCA on the features before training.

```
control = trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                       number = 10,
                       repeats = 5,
                       p = 0.9)

knnFit = train(x = trainingDigit,
               y = label,
               metric = "Accuracy",
               method = "knn",
               trControl = control,
               preProcess = "pca")
```

I don't understand how to represent my data for training resulting in an error:

> Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) :
>     cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

My training data is represented as follows ([`Rdata` file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xa8w351hxv6lpm/data.RData?dl=0)):

```
List of 10
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.934 0.979 0.877 0.853 0.945 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.807 0.98 0.803 0.978 0.969 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.745 0.883 0.776 0.825 0.922 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.892 0.817 0.835 0.84 0.842 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.752 0.859 0.881 0.884 0.855 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.798 0.969 0.925 0.921 0.873 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.964 0.93 0.97 0.857 0.926 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.922 0.939 0.958 0.946 0.867 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.969 0.947 0.916 0.861 0.86 ...
 $ : num [1:400, 1:324] 0.922 0.933 0.978 0.968 0.971 ...
```

Labels as follows ([`.Rdata` file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnietdtok7n4itj/testClass_new.RData?dl=0)):

```
List of 10
 $ : num [1:400] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 ...
 $ : num [1:400] 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your representation of the data. Try this before you start training:

```
label <- factor(c(label, recursive = TRUE))
trainingDigit <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, trainingDigit))
```

You need to massage your data into a data.frame or data.frame-like format with a single column representing your different outcomes with the other columns being features for each outcome.

Also, if you want to do classification, not regression, your outcomes need to be a `factor`.

To be clear, I tried to run the training code as follows, and it works just fine.

```
library(caret)
load("data.RData")
load("testClass_new.RData")

label <- factor(c(label, recursive = TRUE))
trainingDigit <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, trainingDigit))

control <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv",
                        number = 10,
                        repeats = 5,
                        p = 0.9)

knnFit <- train(x = trainingDigit,
                y = label,
                metric = "Accuracy",
                method = "knn",
                trControl = control,
                preProcess = "pca")
```

Comment: I tried running your code.. 
I get the same error , i only changed the path.